# Make http call faster in handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I am implementing actionable Push actions. i am getting following method after click action.

```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {



        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary* jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [jsonDict setValue:[[jsonArray1 valueForKey:@"uid"] lowercaseString] forKey:@"actionby"];
        [jsonDict setValue:@"" forKey:@"alid"];
        [jsonDict setValue:strOTP forKey:@"tp"];
        [jsonDict setValue:@"1" forKey:@"txf"];
        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict
                                                           options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        NSString *trimmedTweet = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
        NSString *nospaceStr = [trimmedTweet stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        NSString *encrypted =@"";

            encrypted = [sharedData testSecKey:nospaceStr];

            if([encrypted length] > 0) {

                encrypted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"enc{%@}",encrypted];

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [SharedData getGatewayURL]]]
                                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                                   timeoutInterval:15];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

                NSString *encodedXML = [encrypted urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", REQUEST_PARAMETER_NAME, encodedXML];
                [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



                NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
                [conn start];


       if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler();
        }

    }
```

Also handle delegate methods. but this response in background is too slow (i have to hit 2 web services)? How to fix this?  how to speed up response?

Comment: create a combined web service...

Comment: @Wain. Thanks for response. but it takes more than min. still can't get response. what could be the issue? is it fine with NSURLConnection.?

Comment: you should use URL session if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i was missing

```
 if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler();
 }
```

I called this when i got last response form server. to know iOS finished my background task.